# How do I create a Freemarker template with n depth?

Tags: java, freemarker

I am trying to use Apache Freemarker to display some data in a json-esque format that is n layers deep. With this unknown, I am trying to output something similar to below:

```
{
  "name": "Human",
  "type": "object",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "weight"
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "Origin"
      "type": "object"
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "fatherOrigin"
          "type": "object"
          "fields": [
             ... 
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "motherOrigin"
          "type": "object"
          "fields": [
             ... 
          ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I wanted to use a while loop that, in pseudocode, looks like this.

```
while(1){
  if (currType is object) {
      print what you know and walk deeper
   }else{
      print your output and break
  }
```

However, freemarker does not support while loops. My alternative is to create a list that that is of a size that is larger than any reasonable depth (30)

Is this an accepted design for this problem? Is there a better way to approach it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `while` loop indeed. The cleanest way I can imagine is `<#list 0.. as _>...</#list>`, but beware, `0..` will only work properly (as an infinite series) with high enough `incompatible_improvements` configuration setting value. `_` is just a plain variable, but meant to express that I don't care about the name.

But, generally, processing nested structures is best done with recursion. Macros and functions support that. Then `#list`-s (if you will need them at all) usually go through an actual list of things that's coming from the data-model, not some range you have constructed as a workaround.

Comment: Recursion via macros is an excellent solution around this. Will try it out. Thanks!